# Using opaque pointers internally in library

Tags: c, struct

When writing a library, you sometimes want to hide implementation details from the user. The ideal tool for this is opaque structs or opaque pointers.

A problem arises when another source file in the library wishes to use data from this struct. For example: this is the header file `apple.h`:

```
typedef struct apple_ Apple;
Apple* new_apple();
void delete_apple(Apple* a);
/* ... */
```

This is the definition of the struct `Apple`:

```
typedef struct apple_ {
  int taste; /* the higher the better */
}
```

Typically, this part resides in `apple.c`.

But what if a `Store` wishes to rank their apples according to taste? This could be `store.c`:

```
#include "apple.h"
void rankApples(Store* store) {
    int t = store->apples[0]->taste; /* unreachable field */
}
```

A solution could be to duplicate the struct definition (I don't want that) or to create a function in `apple.[hc]`: `int taste_apple(Apple* a) { return a->taste; }`, but I'd rather that users don't know how tasty apples are.

How can this be solved? Should I create another header file used by both `apple.c` and `store.c`? How do I stop users from including that header file?

Comment: "yes" and "don't provide it with your redist package" to answer the last two questions. You obviously need the header when *you* are building the lib, but there should be no requirement you "ship" that header with your lib and stock header.

Comment: WhozCraig, I suppose that's the best answer. If you post it as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When hiding library detail from consuming clients, it is not uncommon to do what you described in your last paragraph. But you don't need to "ship the details" with your lib and public header.

For example:

**mylib.h**

```
#ifndef MYLIB_H

typedef struct Data Data;

void Func(Data *data);

#endif
```

**mylibint.h**

```
#ifndef MYLIB_H_INTERNAL
#define MYLIB_H_INTERNAL

struct Data
{
    // implementation goes here
    int value;
};

#endif
```

**mylib.c**

```
#include "mylib.h"
#include "mylibint.h"


Data *GetData()
{
    return calloc(1, sizeof(Data));
}

void FreeData(Data *data)
{
    free(data);
}

void DoSomething(Data * data)
{
    // do something with data
}
```

In doing so, your library will build, consuming both headers while doing so. The only header you need to ship with it is `mylib.h`. Later, a client can do this:

**client.c**

```
#include "mylib.h"

int main()
{
    Data *data = GetData();
    DoSomething(data);
    FreeData(data);
}
```

And they are left blissfully unaware of what `Data` is besides some opaque type.

Comment: I am new in opaque pointer so it may be a silly question that's why instead of asking a new question I though it would be better to comment first on existing question! I created `mylib.h` `mylibint.h` `mylib.c` and `client.c` and everything is working fine but I don't know how shipping only mylib.h and mylib.c will make client.c work because where forward declaration of `struct Data` will find it's definition also we are using mylibint.h in mylib.c so when compiling the code mylibint.h should be present in the working directory of the client? won't it? btw are we talking about static linking?

Comment: I am sorry if I am spamming here but my doubt need to be clear! I think we are doing one this we are compiling `mylib.h` `mylibint.h` and `mylib.c` into an object file called `mylib.o` and the shipping `mylib.h` and `mylib.o` then client is using `mylib.h` in his program an creating another object file say `client.o` and then linking both `client.o` and `mylib.o` into final executable? Whatever I have said in above two comments is right or wrong! Please clarify!

Answer (score 0):

You want the store to know a piece of information, but you are not willing to give it to them. That just doesn't make sense.

You can either make `apple` structure public to both files (that might mean separating it and including it by both, but not giving it to the user), or as you said, create a function that would retrieve the taste of an apple.

However, I'd say that if the taste is going to be used for the ranking purposes only, why don't you just create a function, let's say `getPoints` a `store` could use to rank the apples?

```
int getPoints(Apple* a) {
    return a->taste*2;
}
```

Comment: I'm willing to give it to the store, but not to the users of the library. I had thought of writing something like your `getPoints` function, but I do not want to expose such information either.

Comment: @RaptorDotCpp: (a) You can declare the private (undocumented) function in an appropriate header that is not made generally available — preferably using a name space that you explicitly reserve for private function names.  (b) If you need to do it, are you sure your users have no reason to know how to do it?  That is, if you need to be able to compare tastiness of apples, why are you adamant that other users of your apple type won't also want to compare tastiness?